# Connect to mongodb with Authentication in log4j configuration

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j

i want to connect to mongodb for logging in log4j and i test connection with admin db (my authenticated and main db) and it is connected successfully but i want to connect to other db than admin (like log db) 
there is my config

```xml
<NoSql name="databaseAppender">
    <MongoDb3 databaseName="log" collectionName="log" server="localhost" port="27017" username="test" password="test"/>
</NoSql>
```

how can i set an authenticate db for my configuration?

Comment: Usually the connection should provide properties "database" and "authenticationSource" (or similar). Otherwise can you connect with [connectionString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks you, i will checkout connectionString using MongoDb4